# Conversion between opencv and javacv

Tags: opencv, javacv

I'm thinning an binary image. I found code done by using opencv. Here is the code.

```
eroded = cv2.erode(img,element)
temp = cv2.dilate(eroded,element)
temp = cv2.subtract(img,temp)
skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skel,temp)
img = eroded.copy()
```

I'm trying to convert this code to java via javacv. Both erosion and dilation completed successfully as follows.

```
skelImg=cvCloneImage(otsuImg);
cvErode(otsuImg, skelImg, null, 1);
cvDilate(skelImg, skelImg, null, 1);
```

But I couldn't find javacv code for cv2.subtract(IplImage,IplImage). Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: consider using [opencv's own java wrappers](http://docs.opencv.org/java/) instead of javacv, which unfortunately builds mostly on deprecated c-structures.

Answer (score 1):

There is one subtract function in Core. See [this](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#subtract%28org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat%29) for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use the javacv wrapper to OpenCV's deprecated API, consider using the following methods from [OpenCV's official Java API](http://docs.opencv.org/java/):

[org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.erode](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#erode(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat))

[org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.dilate](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#dilate(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat))

[org.opencv.core.Core.subtract](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#subtract(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat))

[org.opencv.core.Core.bitwise_or](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#bitwise_or(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat))